# C++ implement AVL Tree

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I have a **TreeSet** class describe a tree in c++:

```
class TreeSet
{
private:
    AVLNode * root;
    int count;

protected:
    void clearRec(AVLNode*root);


public:
    TreeSet();
    ~TreeSet();
    void clear();
    // print out the set in ascending order
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const TreeSet& t);


    int add(int val);
}
```

and a **AVL node** class to represent an AVl node:

```
class AVLNode {
public:
    int key;            // data 
    AVLNode* left;      // left child
    AVLNode* right;     // right child
    int balance;        // balance factor

    AVLNode(int key) {
        this->key = key;
        left = right = NULL;
        balance = 0;
    }
    AVLNode(int key, int balance) {
        this->key = key;
        this->balance = balance;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};
```

Here is my implementation for add function when there is nothing in TreeSet

```
int TreeSet::add(int val) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        AVLNode newNode(val);
        root = &newNode;        
        count++;
    }
}
```

The **main** function:

```
int main() {
    TreeSet set, temp, *subSet;
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open("input.txt");
    char command;
    int val;
    try
    {
        while (ifs >> command) {
            switch (command) {
            case 'a': // add an element to the set
                ifs >> val;
                set.add(val);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I have a txt file with line
a 4

it doesn't print out 4 to screen. Can you help me solving this?

Comment: I cannot see the code where you actually print the tree.

Comment: In main function, but the problem is solved

Comment: @DuyDuy If the problem is solved: Please add an answer or comment, how (to let others learn from you - that is the goal of the SO platform). THX :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
    AVLNode newNode(val);
    root = &newNode;
```

newNode is local variable, you take the pointer to this var, but `newNode` goes out of scope at the end of `add` method, so you have dangling pointer. You need to allocate AVLNode on heap, by `new` operator:

```
    root = new AVLNode(val);
```